# Tablet Emulators, CSS Mobile Media Tags

Tags: css, mobile, media-queries

I am using this code:

```
@media (min-device-width: 400px) and (max-device-width: 1020px) {

.gform_wrapper.two-column_wrapper ul.gform_fields.gform_column {float:none !important;}

}
```

When I view the website on the actual tablet, the code seems to work fine. However, when I view the site on a tablet emulator website, it doesn't work.

Am I doing something wrong with the syntax ?

Comment: Also the code doesn't work when I physically try to change the width of my browser on my desktop... Not sure what's wrong here..

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand the emulator is not treated as a "device", therefor the media query does not apply to it. The emulator is likely opening the website in an iFrame, so a simple min/max-width query will apply.

Answer (score 1):

change this:

```
@media (min-device-width: 400px) and (max-device-width: 1020px) {

.gform_wrapper.two-column_wrapper ul.gform_fields.gform_column {float:none !important;}

}
```

to this:

```
@media (min-width: 400px) and (max-width: 1020px) {

.gform_wrapper.two-column_wrapper ul.gform_fields.gform_column {float:none !important;}

}
```

[**Here**](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/layouts/rwd-fundamentals/use-media-queries) is why:

> It is also possible to create queries based on `*-device-width;` though
>   this practice is **strongly discouraged**.
>
> The difference is subtle but very important: `min-width` is based on the
>   size of the browser window, whereas `min-device-width` is based on the
>   size of the screen. Unfortunately some browsers, including the legacy
>   Android browser may not report the device width properly and instead
>   report the screen size in device pixels instead of the expected
>   viewport width.
>
> In addition, using `*-device-width` can prevent content from adapting on
>   desktops or other devices that allow windows to be resized because the
>   query is based on the actual device size, not the size of the browser
>   window.